# How do I perform a div search in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code-

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var $search = $("#search");
    $("#l").find( $search ).css('color','red');
});
```

$("#l") is the div I want to search in.

Comment: whats this? greek or latin? :)

Comment: what do you mean???
its english.....duh!!!

Comment: please elaborate your question. do you want to "highlight your search?". BTW there is english.stackexchange for that :)

Comment: yep i do want to highlight my search....thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var $search = $("#search");
    $("#l").children().find('#'+$search.val()).css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: but my "#search" textbox isn't in the "#l" div, please help

Comment: It doesn't need to be. The query just says take the input from the `#search` textbox and try to match an element with the id of what the user has typed in the `#l` list.

Comment: Added `.children()` so it searches the lists children instead of the list itself. (Guessing here that `#l` refers to a `<ul>` element.

Comment: So you want to highlight the text in the div in red right? If so check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230714/jquery-how-to-highlight-certain-words-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){

    var searchTerm = "Hello";
    $("#l:contains('+ searchTerm +')").css('color','red');
});
```

Just use `:contains('value')` selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#text

[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)