# highlighting specific words in a string of text using different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting one string and one array of strings from api, for example as below. (These string and array is dynamic)

```
samplestring = "You've gotta dance like there's nobody watching, Love like you'll never be hurt, Sing like there's nobody listening, And live like it's heaven on earth.";

samplearray = dance,love,sing (The count is also dynamic)
```

I want to highlight the strings from samplearray if they are in samplestring,

Something Like

[image]

is there anyway to achieve this by css or js?

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622808/html-changing-colors-of-specific-words-in-a-string-of-text) but I can not use this because my string is dynamic. I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680080/how-to-highlight-different-search-results-with-mark-js) also, but I am not sure how to implement.

Comment: what kind of style do you want? all styles should be same?

Comment: "I want this thing.  Can I do this thing?" are indicators of too broad questions

Comment: Also there's not a dynamic string. A string is a string. Somewhere you're calling an API and getting a string in the response. Somewhere else you take your string and put it in your DOM.

Comment: You can loop over the array and wrap each word that you find with a span tag. Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qp6bv0L8/)

Comment: See also [How do you highlight all the words on the page that match an array of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6987328/215552), [How to compare string with array of words and highlight words in string that match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46123744/215552), ... this question is asked multiple times a month on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can search every words and replace the source string with the tags.
Set it using `innerHTML`

```js
var samplestring = "You've gotta dance like there's nobody watching, Love like you'll never be hurt, Sing like there's nobody listening, And live like it's heaven on earth.";

const samplearray = ["dance","Love","Sing"]

samplearray.forEach(str => {
  samplestring = samplestring.replaceAll(str, `<span>${str}</span>`)
})

root.innerHTML = samplestring
```

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Although this work, this won't work if the word starts the same. e.g a list of allergens in ingredients string. if you have wheat and wheatflour, that code will only highlight wheat even though wheatflour will still be in samplearray.